# How to write a function to sieve element in a list using erlang

Tags: erlang

I was ask to write a function in erlang that given a list of integer and an integer, will return all integer smaller than or equal to the integer. Example sive ([1,2,3,4,5 ],3)=[1,2,3]

Comment: and what you have already did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions are explained here:

- http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html
- https://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thanks for the site.But please I'll like to use a function instead

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use function instead you can check [filter/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2).